# how to delete some text in the class attribute using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, attributes

I want to delete the text in the  **Class** attribute, the  **product _**  and  **produk_row**  in element  **.tableProduct** . How can I achieve that with jQuery? Thank you.

the HTML

```html
<div class "tableProduct">
  <div class="produk_Product Products produk_row"> image.jpg </div>
  <div class="produk_stok produk_row"> 9 </ div>
    <div class="product_product_row price"> 120000 </div>
  </div>
```

I want it to just be:

```html
<div class "tableProduct">
  <div class="FotoProduk"> image.js </div>
  <div class="stock"> 9 </div>
  <div class="price"> 120000 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Look into JQuery's addClass() and removeClass() methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the removeClass and addClass function.

```
$("div").removeClass("produk_Product Products produk_row").addClass("FotoProduk");
$("div").removeClass("produk_stok produk_row").addClass("stock");
$("div").removeClass("product_product_row price").addClass("price");

<div class "tableProduct">
  <div class="produk_Product Products produk_row"> image.jpg </div>
  <div class="produk_stok produk_row"> 9 </ div>
  <div class="product_product_row price"> 120000 </div>
</div>
```